# pass a range of values in bash as vector in Rscript

Tags: bash, rscript

I want to pass a range of numbers from bash as argument of a R script.

As an example I made the following R script, which I will call "myscript.R":

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
test<-as.numeric(unlist(args[1]))
write.csv(as.matrix(test),file="buu.csv",,row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
```

Then I run it in bash using as argument a range of values:

```
Rscript myscript.R seq 9000 50 14000
```

However it did not work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `Rscript ... $(seq 9000 50 14000)`?

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives me only the first value of the list